# Unable to build after Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.2

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

After I updated my visual studio to 8.2. I can't build anything now for my xamarin project. As shown below is the error.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.701/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(5,5):

Error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Offset must be within plus or minus 14 hours.
Parameter name: offset
  at System.DateTimeOffset.ValidateOffset (System.TimeSpan offset) [0x0004a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/DateTimeOffset.cs:908 
  at System.DateTimeOffset..ctor (System.DateTime dateTime) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/DateTimeOffset.cs:82 
  at System.DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime (System.Int64 fileTime) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/DateTimeOffset.cs:522 
  at System.IO.FileStatus.GetLastWriteTime (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, System.Boolean continueOnError) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileStatus.Unix.cs:187 
  at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_LastWriteTimeCore () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystemInfo.Unix.cs:60 
  at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_LastWriteTimeUtc () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystemInfo.cs:115 
  at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_LastWriteTime () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystemInfo.cs:109 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.GetLastWriteTime (System.String fullPath) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:513 
  at System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc (System.String path) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:239 
  at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets+CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk (Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets task, System.Byte[] settingsHash) [0x00008] in :0 
  at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets+CacheReader..ctor (Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets task) [0x00015] in :0 
  at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore () [0x00018] in :0 
  at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00023] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810  (MSB4018) (b)

Comment: Have you tried to delete bin and obj folders, do a package restore, clean and build – in this order?

Comment: I'm a newbie to Visual Studio. Where are bin and obj folders are located?

Comment: I've deleted bin and obj Project, Project.Android and Project.iOS then package restore, clean and build. I can't still build. 

The error also change
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error MSB4018: The "CreateAssetPackManifest" task failed unexpectedly.

Comment: Please do the process for every bin and obj folder in your platform and NetStandard projects and then provide a full log of the error.

Comment: I deleted every bin obj. I still can't build. The old and new solution for Xamarin still shown the initial error above.

Comment: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Offset must be within plus or minus 14 hours.
Parameter name: offset
  at System.DateTimeOffset.ValidateOffset (System.TimeSpan offset) [0x0004a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/DateTimeOffset.cs:908 
  at System.DateTimeOffset..ctor (System.DateTime d

Comment: For me it looks like you have a problem with a DateTime object. Probably you are living in a different time zone than UTC +0. If you have e.g. UTC -1 or less please check your code for something like this: `DateTime.MinValue.ToLocalTime()`